# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 89; The reference to entity "pub" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I tried to copy this code on my blog html (blogger)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://udbaa.com/slider.php?section=General&pub=241892&ga=g&side=random"></script>
```

When I tape save , I get :

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 89; The reference to entity "pub" must end with the ';' delimiter.

I added ':' to the "pub" but the same result.
If my code is wrong, correct for me.

Answer (score 0):

In XML, the `&` is the start of an entity declaration. You can't just have regular `&` characters in your XML.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) **must not appear in their literal form**, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, **they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings " `&amp;` " and " `&lt;` " respectively.**

So, in your URL when it sees `&pub` it's expecting to see `$pub;` and resolve the "pub" entity. If you are going to parse the HTML as XML, you need to make it

What you would need to do is encode the `&` and use the amp entity reference, making it `&amp;pub`.